# How to find out your account password while you are inside the account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords

(I want to know the password, I do not want to change the password)

I am now in my account on the computer,

I want to know the password for the account,

is there a way or a program that shows you the password for the account?

Comment: Is it **your** computer?

Comment: Ask the administrator

Comment: I am an administrator, I wanted to know if there is a way to hack computer password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Windows uses [one-way-encryption](https://www.technipages.com/definition/one-way-hash-function) to store your password. This means that Windows can check whether your password is the right one, but there's no way it can display your password. So, also, anyone who accesses your PC can't "steal" your password.

See [this answer for some details](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157922/how-are-windows-10-hashes-stored-if-the-account-is-setup-using-a-microsoft-accou) on how Windows achieves this.

See [Wikipedia for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) on how one-way encryption works.